# Rendering ZK component based on the server response

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, zk

i have the following field in my ZK controller

private boolean hasError; and getter setter for this also is defined

and set the value for that like the following

```
setHasError(true);
                throw new WrongValueException(c,
                        "Invalid value: Must be 0  or 1 ");
```

now i try to access the the above field like the following in the zk page like the following.

```
<div width="95%" style="margin: 5px auto" align="left" if="${hasError}">
             <separator height="5px" />
                <hlayout >

                    <label zclass="headerText12 bold" style="color: red;">
                         some message
                    </label>

                </hlayout>

            </div>
```

I have put this `if="${hasError}"` condition on div but still the value is not getting shown when `hasError` field is set to `true`

could some one help me please.

Comment: do you using MVC or MVVM approach?

Comment: Your EL expressions won't access the controller's attribute. You have to add `$composer` in front of `hasError` (read [here](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/Controller/Composer#Retrieve_Composer_in_EL_Expressions)). But even then, keep in mind that the if will only be evaluated once at creation time. If you change `hasError` after the initial reading of the zul, it will not do anything. You could try instead to append or detach the div in code.